# Mod rewrite won't work on IIS7.5 for Arabic characters

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, utf-8, windows-server-2008-r2

I just set up a server with Windows Server 2008 R2. After installation and running some website in PHP, I find out mod_rewrite won't work for UTF-8 Arabic characters, and it prints ???? question marks instead.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Would you expand on "mod_rewrite won't work for Arabic characters"? Are you using this to redirect or rewrite routes, perhaps? Supplying your mod_write configuration might be useful too.

Comment: I use mod rewrite for redirecting but as I mentioned it works well for english characters but when i try to use arabic charachters it returns ??? Instead of correct arabic words.

Comment: Great! Let's see your config please. I take it this is in an .htaccess or an Apache vhost config?